# Error running in SuperDevMode (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, gwt, errai

Below is the error I see when trying to run Errai with Maven:

```
$mvn gwt:run-codeserver -Dgwt.bindAddress=0.0.0.0 -Dgwt.module=app.App
```

What could be missing in my dependency? When I run with:

```
$mvn gwt:run
```

There's no problem and the apps works fine.

**Error:**

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactoryImpl
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.searchForTypeBySource(UnifyAst.java:983)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.access$1500(UnifyAst.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:364)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:433)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:237)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:243)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  ... 44 more
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(42): GWT.create(MarshallerFactory.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(42): (MarshallerFactory) GWT.create(MarshallerFactory.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(42): MarshallerFramework.marshallerFactory = (MarshallerFactory) GWT.create(MarshallerFactory.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBinaryOperation
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(42): MarshallerFramework.marshallerFactory = (MarshallerFactory) GWT.create(MarshallerFactory.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(40): {
[INFO]   InitVotes.waitFor(MarshallerFramework.class);
[INFO]   MarshallerFramework.marshallerFactory = (MarshallerFactory) GWT.create(MarshallerFactory.class);
[INFO]   ParserFactory.registerParser(new MarshallerFramework$1());
[INFO]   InitVotes.voteFor(MarshallerFramework.class);
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(37): {
[INFO]   Object.$clinit();
[INFO]   {
[INFO]     InitVotes.waitFor(MarshallerFramework.class);
[INFO]     MarshallerFramework.marshallerFactory = (MarshallerFactory) GWT.create(MarshallerFactory.class);
[INFO]     ParserFactory.registerParser(new MarshallerFramework$1());
[INFO]     InitVotes.voteFor(MarshallerFramework.class);
[INFO]   }
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(37): {
[INFO]   Object.$clinit();
[INFO]   {
[INFO]     InitVotes.waitFor(MarshallerFramework.class);
[INFO]     MarshallerFramework.marshallerFactory = (MarshallerFactory) GWT.create(MarshallerFactory.class);
[INFO]     ParserFactory.registerParser(new MarshallerFramework$1());
[INFO]     InitVotes.voteFor(MarshallerFramework.class);
[INFO]   }
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
[INFO]       [ERROR] at MarshallerFramework.java(37): private static final void $clinit();
[INFO] 
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
[ERROR] [INFO] [ERROR] Compiler returned false
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:93)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:54)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:88)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:51)
```

Comment: Have a look at http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201210.mbox/%3CCAEayHEN98nCkbwVrywcf1TW-eCFOywNNhB579uZYHSx%3DpK1z-w%40mail.gmail.com%3E, it could be related. Try `mvn compile gwt:run-codeserver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing dependency for codeserver which is: `com.google.gwt.gwt-codeserver`

I personally had problems with running it through maven. I use eclipse run instead:
NAME: `GWT_CODESERVER`
MAIN CLASS: `com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer`
ARGUMENTS: `-workDir ../.codeserver -src src/main/java yourpackage.YourModule`
VM ARGS: `-Xms750m -Xmx750m -XX:PermSize=200M -XX:MaxPermSize=200M`
CLASSPATH: `(external jar) gwt-codeserver.jar`